# Python / Pandas: Appending part of the specific row to rest of the rows in large dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How can I update rest of the dataframe with specific part of the row?

Here is what I have for example:

| Name | Surname | Barcode | Email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jo | Johy | 098899899 | jo@jo.com |
| Marc | Mullan |  |  |
| Dino | Dukky |  |  |

Expected output:

| Name | Surname | Barcode | Email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jo | Johy | 098899899 | jo@jo.com |
| Marc | Mullan | 098899899 | jo@jo.com |
| Dino | Dukky | 098899899 | jo@jo.com |

I simply need to overwrite all values for Barcode and Email to rest of the rows with value in row 0 while keeping rest of the columns intact.

I know how to do it just by appending dictionary (Barcode:value, Email:value) to the rest of the dataframe but I'm interested in what would be fastest and least memory consuming approach since my DF is large (over 100 million records).

Comment: so you simply want [`ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html)? use `df[['Barcode','Email']]=df[['Barcode','Email']].ffill()` or `df[['Barcode','Email']]=df[['Barcode','Email']].fillna(method='ffill')`?

Comment: @AnuragDabas works great. Put it in answer if you want.